# Is it possible to use the following pre-loading after page load script for an iframe or div?

Tags: javascript

I found this script online and it works great for pre-loading images after page load.

I was wondering if I can use this to pre-load either an iframe or a div that contains an iframe.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BgUA2/

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function preloader() {
if (document.images) {
    var ch001 = new Image();
    var ch002 = new Image();

    ch001.src = "http://a.net/a.jpg";
    ch002.src = "http://a.net/b.jpg";
}
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
var oldonload = window.onload;
if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
} else {
    window.onload = function() {
        if (oldonload) {
            oldonload();
        }
        func();
    }
}
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes you can use it to pre-load the `div` containing the iframe but you will have to edit your preloader function for divs

Comment: @stackErr Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: I would need to see your HTML, and you need to specify if you need to create a new div with iframe or pre-load an existing one?

Comment: @stackErr http://jsfiddle.net/BgUA2/ The javascript is the very first one. The other one is to toggle show and hide of the div. The Div in question is called #slindingDiv. The iframe is homedepot.com. Thanks

Comment: since homedepot is not the same domain as your website there is no way to ensure that the iframe will be loaded before your webpage is.

Comment: @stackErr The actual iframe is. Home depot is just an example so I don't display my actual url there. All I want to do is make sure that the iframe is pre-loaded, but I don't want to load it with the page since the iframe is big. It is however, hidden by default, that's also why I don't mind it loading after page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS trick:

```
iframe {
    background-image: url("http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading2.gif");   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Also, you can add `background-size: 10%;` do make the spinner smaller.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b43zK/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you misunderstood my question. I want to pre-load an iframe or div after page load with that script. That script is used for images now, and I'm not sure how to edit it for divs or iframes.

Comment: @guisasso Please add a pseodocode to make your question clearer.